# Need Multiple Sudoku Solutions

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sudoku

I'm trying to `output multiple sudoku solutions` in my program. For example, when You enter this as input:

```
8..6..9.5.............2.31...7318.6.24.....73...........279.1..5...8..36..3......
```

`.`'s denote blank spaces. Numbers represent already-filled spaces. The output should be a sudoku solution like so:

```
814637925325149687796825314957318462241956873638274591462793158579481236183562749
```

However, I want to output multiple solutions. This would be all the solutions that should be printed:

```
814637925325149687796825314957318462241956873638274591462793158579481236183562749
814637925325941687796825314957318462241569873638472591462793158579184236183256749
834671925125839647796425318957318462241956873368247591682793154579184236413562789
834671925125839647796524318957318462241956873368247591682793154519482736473165289
834671925125839647796524318957318462241965873368247591682793154519482736473156289
```

But my program only prints out one solution. 
Could anyone help me come up with a way to print out multiple solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia says that sudoku puzzles typically has only one solution.

Comment: Well i want to test for puzzles with multiple solutions

Comment: Interesting algorithm. I suspect the solution is to change your last `return true` to something that tells the rest of the application 'in my state, k=4 is a valid answer', and then continues to check k= 5-9. Of course to do this, you would have to store multiple board states, rather than just modifying the original 'arr' board.  @naysayers..."typically" only has one solution.

Comment: @Loki Astari then how should i go about to output a set of numbers in a grid then?
Rollie yes it does. Do you have any tips on how to go to output an alternate set of solutions?

Comment: I thought there were no multiple sudoku with number of hints more than 16... http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0749

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return here:

```
  if(testTheNumber(arr, row, column+1)==true)
  {
    return true;
  }
```

You should instead let the algorithm try all the possible k values.
And you should only print the solution at the end (when you've found all the numbers).

Comment: So would I simply print when row == 9?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply not stopping your recursion when you find a solution. For example, something like:

```
if (row == 9) {
    // print solution here
    return true;
}
```

and remove the other `return true;` and just recurse:

```
testTheNumber(arr, row, column+1);
```

The above will stop the recursion when you find a solution (by reaching the end row), and will also continue trying more numbers after that point.

Also, you may have a bug in the `if(k == 10)` part, because `k` should never be 10 at that point. You will want to set the cell to 0 after existing from the `k` loop.

Comment: So would I simply print after row == 9 and then return true? And then just remove the testTheNumber(arr, row, column+1) return true?

Comment: Well don't remove the recursive call, just the `if` part and the `return true` part.

Comment: But since my function is a boolean function, wouldn't I need some sort of bool to evaluate the function? or would i simply put return testTheNumber(arr, row, column+1);?

Comment: If I remove the if(testTheNumber(arr, row, column+1) == true) then arr[row][column]->number would be 0 and would give me a false solution I think..

Comment: No, don't return at all! Just call the function. In fact, with these changes you're not using the return value anywhere (because you're printing the solution at the deepest recursion level). So you could change it to `void`.

Comment: So would I simply cout the solution if row == 9? Then how would I get it so that if there was no possible number solutions it would print out an error? The reason I had my boolean was to denote if it was true, i would cout my answer. If not I would cout an error.

Comment: Ok, you could still return a flag saying whether you found any solution at all. In that case, you might do something like `found |= testTheNumber(arr, row, column+1);` and then `return found` to say whether you found anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18445/discussion-between-user1567909-and-greg-hewgill)